# Angular formly select shows blank drop down list from backend api call

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I am trying to display data in drop down select list using angular formly. The drop down list appear to be blank. Here is the code snippet. Can some please help??

component.ts

```
 this.fields = [
  {
        key: 'Branch',
        type: 'select',
        defaultValue: 'develop',
        templateOptions: {
          required: true,
          label: 'Branches',
          description: 'Select the Branch to deploy in test',
          options: this.artifactory.getArtifacts('star')
        }
]
```

service.ts

```
 getArtifacts(artifact: string) {
    let data: Observable<string[]> = of([]);

    let artifactType = new HttpParams().set('artifact', artifact)
    data = this.httpClient.get<string[]>(`${environment.api}branches`, { params: artifactType }).pipe();
    return data;
  }
```

html

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
    <formly-form [form]="form" [fields]="fields"></formly-form>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to define valueProp and labelProp values in templateOptions as per your api response